# Groovy Console not outputing old values

Tags: java, groovy

I've got a weird problem while testing some code in Groovy Console. The following code:

```
class GameCharacter
{
    def hp
    def mp
    def showInfo
}

c = new GameCharacter(hp: 0, mp: 0)

c.showInfo = {println "HP: ${hp} | MP: ${mp}"}

c.showInfo()

c.with{hp = 100 ; mp = 90}

c.showInfo()
```

Gives me following output:

```
HP: 100 | MP: 90
HP: 100 | MP: 90
```

Why the first `p.showInfo()` call didn't show me the first zeroed values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am actually surprised this code works for you. I get this exception in Groovy Console:

```
Exception thrown
Mar 30, 2011 2:40:47 PM org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.StackTraceUtils sanitize
WARNING: Sanitizing stacktrace:
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: hp for class: ConsoleScript0
```

So it looks to me like showInfo is supposed to print the fields you have in GameCharacter. To fix your code you can either a) assign the closure within the class GameCharacter:

```
class GameCharacter
{
    def hp
    def mp
    def showInfo = {println "HP: ${hp} | MP: ${mp}"}
}
```

or b) you can add the closure via meta programming if you want to add it later:

```
class GameCharacter
{
    def hp
    def mp
}

c.metaClass.showInfo = {println "HP: ${hp} | MP: ${mp}"}
```

You'll get the correct result for both implementation:

```
HP: 0 | MP: 0
HP: 100 | MP: 90
```

Comment: Using a) it worked, but nothing changed with b), I still got the zeroed values. I actually want it to be dynamic (I'm learning and doing tests). Thanks!

Comment: Just tried it again with Groovy 1.7.10. Both implementations should give you the same result. Let me know if you need additional help with one of them not working.

Comment: Now it was weird. I changed the mp value to 91 instead of 90, compiled, ran and it still showed me 90! Is that a Groovy Console behavior (or a bug)? I closed it and opened again, paste the code and now it throws the Exception you mentioned. And b) works.

Comment: Groovy Console only executes Groovy scripts. The code you paste in does not get compiled. Alternatively, you can try your code on the [Groovy Web Console](http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/).

Comment: Looking at the exception message, it says that it tried to find the 'hp' property within the ConsoleScript, not the GameCharacter class. The code works if I change the closure to {c -> println "HP: ${c.hp} | MP: ${c.mp}"} and call it by c.showInfo(c) . How can I refer to "this" within the closure (like "HP: ${this.hp}" ) ? I believe that is the real problem...

Comment: If you don't pass the GameCharacter object into the closure "this" refers to the ConsoleScript. If you don't want to pass in GameCharacter you can refer to the fields like this: c.showInfo = {println "HP: ${c.hp} | MP: ${c.mp}"}.

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm ;)